# How to auto save work on visual studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

There are some extensions for auto saving work on other versions of VS but couldn't find anything for VS2017.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a plugin you can install called [NoMorePanicSave2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PhilippDolder.NoMorePanicSave2017)  It saves everything when the editor loses focus.  Doesn't work perfectly (sometimes you have to tab back in to get it to save), but it's the best thing I could find that's close to Intellij's auto save.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: @DavidPostill You really think this answer (which actually answers the question) is worth deleting just because of the inconvenience of making someone google for the name?  I understand why you'd downvote, but not why it should be deleted.  It provides valuable information (albeit in an inconvenient way).  Deleting this information would hurt others more than help them, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2017 has such as option.

Go to menu *Tools > Options > Environment > AutoRecover* and set the parameters:

[image]

Comment: Is this different from autosave behavior? Can I change it to seconds instead of minutes?

Comment: @AaronFranke: Visual Studio can only be modified by Microsoft.

Comment: This is not the same thing at all. It recovers documents in case of crashes.